# Filtering spcific with checkboxes

Tags: checkbox

My question is that I want a filtering system that will filter by checked checkboxes. 
The tool is to my comparison website where I compare TV packages.

1. my visitors should filter the packages by the tv-channels they want to se.

example;
Checkbox 1: Discovery
Checkbox 2: Animal PLanet
Checkbox 3: Disney Channel

Output should be the matching TV-package
Package 1: (contains Discovery and Disney channel)
Package 2: (contains Animal Planet, Disney channel)
Package 3: (contains Animal Planet)

So if checkbox 1 is checked it should only show package 1.
if checkbox 1 + checkbox 2 is checked it should say "No match found, but this package was was closest to your choice"
if checkbox 2 + checkbox 3 is checked it should only show package 2 which match the visitors choice exactly.

I hope your can help me out. I have been searching a lot after this specific solution without any success.

Comment: What language / what library/ what?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be in Jquery. i have seen some simular filtering examples, but no one there are like my wish above.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but... I'll take a shot.  Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a0nnrfua/

I think a lot really depends on how you intend to define "closest", but presuming a jQuery solution and hopefully your browser requirements aren't TOO far in the past, you could use the data- attributes and jQuery to come up with some relatively simple functions.  Or even use the value portions of the checkboxes really.

Psuedocode, it would look like:

1. Define a click or change handler to detect whenever a checkbox has been touched/changed.
2. Define a function that will scan all checked items and pass the values into your "closest package" function.
3. Based on the results of that function, filter your package selection so that your choices are highlighted or marked in some way.

So let's presume the following HTML markup:

```
    <h3>TV Channels</h3>

<div id="TVChannelSelections">
    <input type="checkbox" class="tvchannel" name="tvchannel" id="tvchannel_Discovery" value="Discovery" />
    <label for="tvchannel_Discovery">Discovery Channel</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="tvchannel" name="tvchannel" id="tvchannel_AnimalPlanet" value="Animal Planet" />
    <label for="tvchannel_AnimalPlanet">Animal Planet</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="tvchannel" name="tvchannel" id="tvchannel_DisneyChannel" value="Disney Channel" />
    <label for="tvchannel_Disney">Disney Channel</label>
    <br/>
</div>

<div id="message"></div>
<h3>Packages</h3>

<div id="FilteredPackages">
    <div class="package deselected" id="Package1" data-channels="Discovery,Disney Channel">Package #1</div>
    <div class="package deselected" id="Package2" data-channels="Animal Planet,Disney Channel">Package #2</div>
    <div class="package deselected" id="Package3" data-channels="Animal Planet">Package #3</div>
</div>
```

So in jQuery, your generic change or click handler would be defined in code:  Note that I'm saying, any element on your page that has the class "tvchannel" defined, if there's ever a change that occurs, run my filter function.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../path/to/jQuery/library"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".tvchannel").on("change", function() {
            FilterMySelectedChannels();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now we can define your Filter function.  We're going to assume two things.  #1, that we want to find all the selected checkboxes and their values.  Then we're going to iterate through the data-channels property of all of our packages (defined as elements with class = "package").  We'll use some form of string comparison and boolean logic to define what a complete match is vs. a close but no cigar match vs. a complete fail.

In order to keep track of things I'm using 3 classes, selected, deselected, and close.

In css, you can decide whether you want notselected to mean "hide the package completely" (i.e. display: none;) or maybe you want it to be visible but greyed out and "struck out" (i.e. text-decoration: strikethrough; color: grey;}

I'm going to use kind of a brute force way of doing the comparison.  There are better array functions and comparison functions in javascript, but this should be relatively clear for most people and I trust the good folks at stackoverflow to chime in with better solutions.  But this should get you started.  :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function FilterMySelectedChannels() {
        $checkedboxes = $(".tvchannel:checked");
        $packages = $(".package");
        var bAnyFound = false;
        $packages.each(function () {
            var bCloseButNoCigar = false;
            var bCompleteMatch = true;
            var packagearray = $(this).data("channels").split(",");
            var $currentPackage = $(this);
            $checkedboxes.each(function () {
                if ($.inArray($(this).val(), packagearray) != -1) {
                    bCloseButNoCigar = true;
                } else {
                    bCompleteMatch = false;
                }
            });

            if (bCompleteMatch) {
                $currentPackage.removeClass("selected").removeClass("deselected").removeClass("close").addClass("selected");
                bAnyFound = true;
            } else if (bCloseButNoCigar) {
                $currentPackage.removeClass("selected").removeClass("deselected").removeClass("close").addClass("close");
            } else {
                $currentPackage.removeClass("selected").removeClass("deselected").removeClass("close").addClass("deselected");
            }
        });

        if (bAnyFound) {
            $("#message").html("The following matches were found");
        } else {
            $("#message").html("No actual matches were found, but here are some close matches based on your selections");
            $(".package.close").removeClass("deselected").removeClass("close").removeClass("selected").addClass("selected");
        }
    }
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    .selected {
        color: red;
        background-color: yellow !important;
    }

    .deselected {
        color: grey;
        text-decoration: strike-through !important;
        background-color: white !important;
    }
</style>
```

There are obvious optimizations that could probably work here, but it's a start for those trying to do something similar.  Note that it assumes that your markup is dynamically generated or properly coded.  If you need to guard against human typos, converting your text using .toLowerCase/UpperCase and using the .Trim functions to eliminate extra space will assist.  But you still have to choose your data values wisely so there's no overlap.   And if you choose them well enough you can use better techniques such as regular expressions and wildcard searches to make the code a bit shorter.

Hope this helps someone!